# SharePoint creating minor version of target page everytime source page changes

Tags: 2013, publishing, versioning, variations, ecm

I am using Variations.

When ever I change some text in source page, SharePoint creates a minor version of same page on target website and asks for it to approve.

Is this normal?

I am asking because it is very confusing. Consider the following scenario.

- I have an English source page in which I wrote 5 paragraphs.
- I have a Spanish target page in which I wrote 10 paragraphs.
- Later I removed a "full stop" from source page and published it.
- After some time SharePoint completely removed those 10 paragraphs from Spanish page and instead pasted 5 paragraphs from English. Although end user doesn't see this because this minor version is not published yet but still isn't it very confusing for the approver that all of a sudden all text is gone and replaced by something else?

How do I make it stop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While creating the target label you can let SharePoint know how you want existing pages to be updated, when the changes are being done to the actual source page

**Users can manually sync updates from source variation pages** will let end-users to choose which one to accept.

**Automatically update target variation pages** will automatically update the target (though in draft state)

You should definitely go with manually sync updates

[image]